# Value of $\sin(π/x)$ for $x$ positive integer

Tags: trigonometry

Is there a known Generalized algebraic formula for the following:

> $\sin(\pi/n)$

here, $n$ is an positive integer

Comment: You can get various infinite families of these values by starting with a known one of them and repeatedly applying a half-angle formula.

Comment: Good question, I think you should put it as $\sin(\frac{2\pi}{n})$ instead,  $n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: $\sin\frac\pi n$ is a very nice and a very general formula.

Comment: $\cos n\theta+i\sin n\theta=(\cos \theta+i\sin \theta)^n$ together with binomial expansion gives you multiple angle formulas for $\cos n\theta$ and $\sin n\theta.$ But (as far as I know) there is no algebraic formula for $\sin(\theta/n)$ in terms of   $\sin \theta, \cos\theta.$

Comment: Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials